# Get mean value from other rows into current row

Tags: r, data.table

I have a soil properties data.table with values for different locations and depths. Some values are NA so I'd like to get the mean values considering the upper and lower layers. In the case of the top layer, I'd take the value from the next one down.

I was able to create a column indicating which are the upper and lower layer for each row and I though about doing a self merge. But I'm completely lost at how to proceed.

Any clues as how to do this? Bellow is an example data.table and what I'd like to achieve. The example considers two locations with 3 layers. But I have multiple locations and some have more layers than others.

```
library(data.table)

# I was able to identify which are the botton and top layers
# using a function to identify the neighboors
dt <- data.table(id = rep(c(1,2), 1, each = 3),
                 depth = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30),
                 val = c(12, 18, 11, 25, 27, 29),
                 bot_l = c(20, 30, NA, 20, 30, NA),
                 top_l = c(NA, 10, 20, NA, 10, 20))


# How can I calculate the average between top and lowe layers?
dt_desired <- data.table(id = rep(c(1,2), 1, each = 3),
                         depth = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30),
                         val = c(12, 18, 11, 25, 27, 29),
                         bot_l = c(20, 30, NA, 20, 30, NA),
                         top_l = c(NA, 10, 20, NA, 10, 20)
                         mean_top_bot = c(18, 11.5, 18, 27, 27, 27))
```

To explain a bit more:

- mean_top_bot[1] = val[depth = 0] + val[depth = 20]. Since I don't have value at depth 0, that would become (NA + 18)/2 = 18 (rm.na = TRUE)
- mean_top_bot[2] = val[depth=10] + val[depth=30] = (12+11)/2
- I calculated the `mean_top_bot` values by hand. That's why I had some errors there :facepal:

**Solution using self merge**

I was able to merge the table with itself, by changin the `by.x` and by.y`parameters. But I have a feeling that I'm doing this in the worst way possible.

```
dt1 <- merge(dt, dt[, .SD, .SDcols = !c('bot_l', 'top_l')],
             by.x = c('id', 'bot_l'),
             by.y = c('id', 'depth'),
             all = TRUE)[order(id, depth)]

   id bot_l depth val.x top_l val.y
1:  1    20    10    12    NA    18
2:  1    30    20    18    10    11
3:  1    NA    30    11    20    NA
4:  1    10    NA    NA    NA    12
5:  2    20    10    25    NA    27
6:  2    30    20    27    10    29
7:  2    NA    30    29    20    NA
8:  2    10    NA    NA    NA    25
```

Are there any easier ways to do this?

Comment: are those numbers correct in the mean_top_bot i.e. can you show the calculation of arriving at 18

Comment: could be related to @akrun's comment, but why is the column `val` not the same in both tables ?

Comment: oops, had an error in the examples I came up with. Updated the question accordingly. I also had some good results using `merge` and `by.x` and `by.y` parameters. But I'm not sure this is the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be easier to use directly `data.table::shift` without computing "top" and "bot" layers.

```
dt <- data.table(id = rep(c(1,2), 1, each = 3),
                 depth = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30),
                 val = c(12, 18, 11, 25, 27, 29))

dt[, v := rowMeans(data.table::setDT(data.table::shift(val, 
                                                       c(1, - 1))),
                   na.rm = TRUE), 
   by = id]
```

Same but with maggrittr :

```
library(magrittr)  

dt[, v := data.table::shift(val, c(1, -1)) %>% data.table::setDT() %>% rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE), 
   by = id]
```

The code above do the mean between previous and next val for a given depth. I suppose the gap between the value and top/bot layers is one and the data are already ordered by id and depth, as in your example.

Comment: Great, I'll check if it works and will get back here. I was not aware of the `data.table::shift` function. Not sure I have the same number of depths for all locations and if that would give me any problem. Also, what happens in the first and last depths? Shift returns NA, which is ignored by `na.rm = TRUE`?

Comment: Exactly, if there is no value before (or after) shift will return NA by default. And for the depth, yes indeed, it will have no impact if it's change across location, I will edit my comment.

Comment: It might also be convenient to save the value as a new column, `dt[, v := rowMeans(...), by=id]`

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the `n` parameter to `shift()` accepts multiple values to create multiple lead/lag vectors. So, one call to `shift()` is sufficient (and picking up Frank's suggestion): `library(magrittr); dt[, mean_top_bot := shift(val, c(-1, 1)) %>% setDT() %>% rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE), id][]`. `magrittr` piping is used here to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I will complete the answer, I will keep a version without magrittr in order to keep the possibility to not add another dependency

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure out, but this can be solved as well by a *rolling mean*:

```
dt[, mean_top_bot := 
     zoo::rollapply(val, width = list(c(-1L, 1L)), FUN = mean, partial = TRUE), id][]
```

> ```
>    id depth val bot_l top_l mean_top_bot
> 1:  1    10  12    20    NA           18
> 2:  1    20  18    30    10         11.5
> 3:  1    30  11    NA    20           18
> 4:  2    10  25    20    NA           27
> 5:  2    20  27    30    10           27
> 6:  2    30  29    NA    20           27
> ```

Two characteristics of `zoo::rollapply()` come in handy:

1. The `width` argument alternatively takes a list of integer offsets. So,  `list(c(-1L, 1L))` refers to the values of the preceeding and subsequent rows while omitting the current row.
2. With `partial = TRUE`, only the subset of indexes that are *in range* are passed to `FUN`. E.g., for the first row, offset -1 refers to index 0 which is out of range. Therefore, only the value of index 2 (offset 1) is passed to `mean()`. Likewise for the last row, where only the second to last value is passed to `mean()`.